# How to access files on the windows server 2003 programmatically

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003, logging

I'm trying to build logviewer for logfiles stored on our server.I know about the logviewers available on codeplex. But I'm looking to build something of my own.
Here's what I need to do first and foremost. The log files are stored on server with address \windows server address\LogFiles. Over here there are various folders with names W3SVC69773105,W3SVC1208646085. Now I can't make head and shoulders of this folder name but each folder represents an application. Inside each folder there are log files for each day. 
I need to be able to get the latest file from the server, and then do parsing on it. I want to know how can I access this file located on server programmatically from my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Insofar as the folder names, it is actually pretty easy to generate them presuming you can access the IIS api. You see, W3CSVC4572 maps to IIS site ID #4572. So, you should have a log folder for each IIS site ID in a rather predictable pattern.

I'll resist my urge to ask why you are in fact reinventing the wheel. Except log parsing is alot less sexy a technology than wheels . . .